# How to write an installer for C# UDF for VBA Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, office-automation

Basically, I know how to write user defined functions in C# for VBA ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx))
I'd like to write an installer which will do the necessary in order to automatically activate and reference my *.tlb in any excel document.
Any information regarding registry entries or settings will be helpful

**Edit:**
With the following I generate a MyPj.tbl and a MyPj.dll (thanks to msbuild).

```
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("afb62cb2-dfa8-4f0f-980b-25f96ad93b92")]
    public interface IGreeting
    {
        string SayHelloWorld { get; }
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("8cd91f78-4e62-4a12-95e0-df82699d4d75")] 
    [ProgId("TestDll.Test")]
    public class Greeting : IGreeting
    {
        public string SayHelloWorld { get { return "Hello, World! "; } }
    }
```

By adding the generated .tbl to my project in Excel (Tools > References ... > Browse), I can access MyPj.Greeting in the Excel VBMacro

```
Sub Test()
    Dim greeter as New MyPj.Greeting
    MsgBox greeter.SayHelloWorld()
End Sub
```

The point is that I don't want to go through "Tools > References ... > Browse". I need to make an installer that will automatically make "SayHelloWorld" available in Excel

Comment: This seems a bit vague to me at this point.  Are you attempting something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651702/how-to-register-a-type-library-in-vba ?  Please post the code you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by auto referencing a type library to any  excel document.  Never tried that and also don't think its a good idea to auto reference custom components.

You can use Visual Studio to create Installer but again running installers mostly requires elevated privileges.

Have a look at Excel-DNA, its an amazing tool/framework, which allows you to wrap all your dlls+tlbs in just a .XLL, then you can use that XLL in any of your workbooks.

See this: http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2015/07/developing-registration-free-com-server.html

Once you have packed the XLL you can set the Reference to that permanently in Excel by `File--> Options ---> Add-ins`